# Android combine armeabi build only lib with new native code

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have an app using old so library compiled only for armeabi, But I have to write some new native code in C file NativeCode.c and compile it with app.
Old library is running correctly only when I set in the build.gradle

```
ndk {
            moduleName "NativeCode"
            abiFilters "armeabi"
        }
```

But when I run app on arm64-v8a phone always get an error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.app.module, PID: 4199
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.app.module-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.app.module-2/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.app.module-2/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libnativecode.so"
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
at com.app.module.util.NativeCode.<clinit>(NativeCode.java:25)
```

Is there any way to tell android studio to build native code only for armeabi ?

Comment: android studio is already building for `armeabi` architecture. The problem is that you are trying to load code from a different arch of your processor

Comment: Yes, when I open apk, in lib/armeabi are all necessary libs, but how to tell the app to take native code lib from there and not from arm64-v8a

Comment: `when I open apk, in lib/armeabi are all necessary libs` Apparently not. An app can only load .so libraries for one architecture. Either provide *all libraries* for arm8 arch or all libraries for arm5 arch or both. More info here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/WqXoeSeBvTI